# How to serialize a List<object> while simultaneously escaping special characters?

Tags: c#, .net, json

We have a very large `List<object>` that we are turning into a json string and then sending to a stored procedure.  To keep things simple for this post, let's say the object looks like this:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And one of the customers is "Bob's Repair Shop".  When the list with this value in it gets serialized, it will contain this:

```
{
    "Name": "Bob's Repair Shop"
}
```

That's ok, right up until we want to send this json into a stored procedure.  When it gets there, that single quote throws an error (which I understand).

Originally we handled this by doing a `.replace("'", "~")` on the json string in the C# code, and then doing the reverse in the stored proc.  That worked for a while. But what we are running into now is that the object we have a List<> of is much more complex that this little example, and we are also dealing with several hundred thousand records in the list. When the json string is this large, the `.replace("'", "~")` throws an `Out of Range` exception.  And let's be honest, this `.replace("'", "~")` approach is a hack anyway.

What I'm hoping to find is a way to serialize our `List<object>` in such a way that the single quotes are escaped during the serialization process. Is this possible? And if so, how?

**EDIT:**

I really should have said this originally.  Sorry I missed it. Here's how the stored proc is receiving the json string:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[name_of_proc]
    @jsonString NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
```

And then we convert the `@jsonString` to a table variable with `OPENJSON`

**EDIT 2:**

how the sp is called:

```
    public void UpdateBulk(List<object> myObject)
    {
        string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject);
        json.replace("'", "~");
        var dParam = new DynamicParameters();
        dParam.Add("@jsonString", json);
        QuerySP<myObject>("name_of_proc", dParam);
    }

    protected IEnumerable<T> QuerySP<T>(string storedProcedure, object param = null)
    {
        using (var db = this.Context)
        {
            var output = db.Query<T>(storedProcedure, param: param, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure,commandTimeout: 32767);
            return output;
        }
    }
```

**EDIT 3:**
The thread pointed to as a possible duplicate asks how to change this:

```
{"key" : "value"}
```

to this:

```
{'key' : 'value'}
```

That's not what I'm asking.  I'm asking how to change this:

```
{
    "Name": "Bob's Repair Shop"
}
```

To this:

```
{
    "Name": "Bob\'s Repair Shop"
}
```

Comment: You should replace `'` with `''`, did you try it?

Comment: But that won't solve the `out of range` error when doing a `.replace()` on a massive string.

Comment: Are you not using a SQL parameter to send the JSON to a sproc?

Comment: You should (always!) use SqlParameters: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters

Comment: Amy, yes we are

Comment: Not a solution for performance, but sounds like the values need to be parameterized.

Comment: @PeterB, we are!

Comment: Ok, I shoudl have said this in the OP. I will clarify how we are sending to the stored proc. One second

Comment: How does `Replace` throw IndexOutOfRangeException :o

Comment: I edited the OP.  Also... thank you for the duplicate points! (I promise I did look before posting and didn't find those!)

Comment: @CaseyCrookston That's how the sproc receives it.  How are you sending the JSON to the sproc?  Are you doing `exec sprocname '<my json>'`?  If so, you aren't using sql parameters to pass your data to the DB.  I'm trying to see how the single quote would cause an error when you pass it as a parameter.

Comment: Show the code that executes the SP call. You're probably using string concatenation where you should use a parameterized query.

Comment: @Amy, see edit 2 in the op

Comment: @CodeCaster see edit 2 in the op

Comment: @CaseyCrookston What is `QuerySP`?

Comment: What are `DynamicParameters` and `QuerySP()`? That's not framework code. Show a [mre]. What everybody here is trying to get at, is that if you properly use parameterized queries, you don't to replace the single quotes. Problem here probably is that you're using homegrown SQL-generating code that messes stuff up.

Comment: @CodeCaster, We are using Dapper. And this is an example straight out of the Dapper documenation.  Hardly "home grown".

Comment: @CaseyCrookston My gut feeling is that some aspect of how you're passing the JSON to the sproc is incorrect.  The single-quote shouldn't be an issue if its passed as a parameter properly.  Maybe I'm wrong, but I feel confident there's an issue there.

Comment: @Dortimer This definitely isn't a dupe of that.

Comment: `QuerySP` doesn't seem to be part of Dapper: https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/search?q=QuerySP&unscoped_q=QuerySP

Comment: @BurnsBA, you are right. I added the definition for `QuerySP`

Comment: @Amy, you could be right.  Although it really does seem like we are correctly using parameters here.  I'll keep digging. But in the meantime... I'm still hoping for an answer to my actual question. Is it possible to handle special characters during the serialization process?

Comment: So what's the actual error you get when you execute the SP with the original JSON?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston Well, I see nothing wrong with that.  This is very puzzling.  Thanks for humoring me for a bit :)

Comment: @CodeCaster: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near 's'.
Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''

Comment: I am trying to put together a simple, stripped down example in a console app

Comment: Your desired output, `{"Name":"Bob\'s repair shop"}` would not be valid JSON - backslash needs to be escaped... do you want `{"Name":"Bob\\'s repair shop"}`?

Comment: @steve16351, yes! thank you

Comment: But it says line 7. What's happening inside your SP, exactly?

Comment: @Amy, ok, I think you are on to something here. I made a super stripped-down example in a console app using "Bob's Repair Shop" and I am not getting the same error we are seeing in our production app.  So you are correct that the JSON is not the problem.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who commented here. You've helped me think through this more critically and realize I was barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

Comment: @EJoshuaS, I don’t think this is a duplicate. That question is about enclosing keys and values with single rather than double quotes. This question is about escaping single quotes within values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a custom JSON converter to perform the replacement on individual `string` instances while the serialization is taking place. This is still using `string.Replace`, but all the string instances should be small at this point.

```
public class EscapeQuotes : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(string);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var escapedValue = ((string)value).Replace("'", "\\'");
        writer.WriteValue(escapedValue);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Customer myObject = new Customer() { Name = "Bob's repair shop" };
var output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject, new EscapeQuotes());
```

Output:

> {"Name":"Bob\\'s repair shop"}

Comment: Awesome Steve! I really appreciate you just answering my question. Love it.  It turns out that the json isn't the problem. I don't know what is (yet) but none the less, I am grateful for this.